# Flash CS4 embedded font style issue

Tags: flash, fonts, coding-style, flash-cs4, embedded-resource

I'm using some fonts embedded in SWF in a program I'm developing. I need to use some specific font style like '37 Thin Condensed' and '26 Ultra Light Italic' etc... how can I specify these style when using fonts? I want to set style using AS3 code...

Answer (score 1):

**An example for Helvetica Neue 37 Thin Condensed**

In your Library panel, in the top right corner, [click for the drop down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hepAp.jpg) and choose "New Font."

For the name field, put "HelveticaNeue37ThinCondensed", for the the font field, choose "Helvetica Neue," for the style field choose "37 Thin Condensed." If you see a button on the bottom right labeled "Advanced" click it.

Under "Linkage" check "Export of ActionScript," and make the class field match the name field from above: "HelveticaNeue37ThinCondensed."

Click OK.

Now you can apply the font in ActionScript:

```
var font1:Font = new HelveticaNeue37ThinCondensed();

var tfoBodyText:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
tfoBodyText.font = font1.fontName;

var tfiBodyText:TextField = new TextField();
tfiBodyText.embedFonts = true;
tfiBodyText.defaultTextFormat = tfoBodyText;
tfiBodyText.text = "This is some text for the new text field.";

addChild(tfiBodyText);
```